# ¿Cómo adquirió "tomate" el significado de "roto o agujero en una prenda de punto"?

Tags: etimología, modismos, españa

El DLE recoge en [**tomate**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZziM5kP) la acepción

> 4. m. coloq. Roto o agujero hecho en una prenda de punto, como una media, un calcetín, un guante, etc.

Esta acepción, por lo que he visto, aparece por primera vez en el DRAE de **1925** y no parece tener una clara relación con la acepción principal de [**tomate**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZziM5kP):

> 1. m. Baya roja, fruto de la tomatera, de superficie lisa y brillante, en cuya pulpa hay numerosas semillas algo aplastadas y amarillas.

No aparece en el Diccionario de Americanismos, por lo que supongo que el uso se restringe a España.

¿Cómo / por qué adquirió **tomate** este significado?

Comment: ¿En que región lo usan? Nunca lo he oído en Colombia

Comment: Curiosamente en Chile a eso le decimos "papa".

Comment: ... y la papa (patata) y el tomate pertenecen a la misma familia botánica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supongo que se refiere al hecho que los rotos tienen una forma algo redonda, y usando un poco la imaginación se puede asociar con un tomate (o una papa):

[image]

y en las medias o calcetines [1](http://www.elmundo.es/mundodinero/2007/01/30/economia/1170147951.html):

[image: Los 'tomates' en los calcetines de Wolfowitz]